# JavaScript won't run when not logged in (WordPress)

Tags: javascript, wordpress

```
<script>

// get all bars
var bars = document.getElementsByClassName('bar');

// determine the highest value
var longest = 0;

for (var bar of bars) {
    if (parseFloat(bar.getAttribute('value')) > longest) {
        longest = parseFloat(bar.getAttribute('value'));
    }
}

// set width relative to the highest value for each bar
for (var bar of bars) {
    bar.style.width = `${parseFloat(bar.getAttribute('value')) / longest * 100}%`;
}



window.onload = function() {
    jQuery("path").attr('stroke-width','4');
};


</script>
```

I have this script which gets two bars and sets the width based on their value (which was dynamically added by Formidable Forms in WordPress. It's always worked fine. However, after switching to use Cloudflare I had a never-ending supply of problems, one of which is that this no longer works unless you're logged in as an admin.

There should be one bar shorter than the other. Instead, they're both always at 100% (unless logged in as an admin, in which case it works fine). The script does run; I put a console.log() into the script, which works. There's no error in the console, just doesn't change the CSS.

[Here's an example of it (not) in action.](https://clevercarbon.io/carbon-results/?entry_key=2wehg)

Comment: What exactly am I supposed to see when I click in the "(not) in action link? It looks ok and I don't get any errors or any console messages. Are you sure this isn't just a caching problem, especially as you are using CloudFlare?

Comment: I wouldn't have thought it'd be a caching issue since the JavaScript runs on page-load and changes the CSS?